# TypeScript reflection for interfaces

Tags: typescript, reflection, interface

Is there a way to find out if interface's property is defined as read only? Say,

```
interface ITest {
    readonly foo: number;
}
```

Now, is there some sort of reflection or trickery for TypeScript to get this information? E.g. something like:

```
let info = Reflect.get(ITest, 'foo');

if (info.isReadOnly()) { ... }
```

Comment: [I'm a fraid not](https://s3.amazonaws.com/gs-geo-images/b194ce6c-f8d5-4df1-a1f0-dfbc44a5f83f.jpg).  Especially with javascripts [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: Interfaces are not available at runtime so I don't think know if you can do reflection calls on them.

Comment: @toskv That's not the point, that was just an example. I don't want run time, I want compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now: https://typescript-rtti.org/.

```js
import { reflect } from 'typescript-rtti';

interface ITest {
    readonly foo: number;
}

let iface = reflect<ITest>().as('interface').reflectedInterface;
let info = iface.getProperty('foo').type;

expect(info.isReadonly).to.be.true;
```

Disclaimer: I am the author

Comment: This is beyond incredible. This is game changer.

Answer (score 2):

Since TypeScript interfaces do not exist at runtime, you cannot use reflection on them. To use reflection I created a class that implements the interface and reflected on the class. However, I was unable to tell if a property is readonly. Not sure if this is a lack of understanding on my part, or a defect. Here is what I tried:

**Code**

```
interface ITest {
  readonly foo: number;
  bar: number;
}
class TestImplementation implements ITest {
  readonly foo: number = 1;
  bar: number = 2;
}
function reflectOnTest() {
  var testImplementation = new TestImplementation();
  var properties: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(testImplementation);
  var fooDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(testImplementation, properties[0]);
  var barDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(testImplementation, properties[1]);
  console.log("foo writable = " + fooDescriptor.writable);
  console.log("bar writable = " + barDescriptor.writable);
}
```

**Output is:**

foo writable = true

bar writable = true